# How to prevent direct access to success page after the payment?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, react-router-dom

I'm using React 18.0, React Router Dom (v6), and I'm trying to implement Paypal Checkout. It works well and after the payment I redirect the user to my success page which contains a download link for the user. The problem is this success page is always reachable. So, I'm trying to allow the access just after the checkout. After then, the user should be redirected to the home.

I tried doing like this but without success:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { getInvoiceUrl } from "../services/invoiceService"

function Success() {
    // Get the state from navigate on the Checkout page
    let { state, pathname } = useLocation()
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    // Check the state in order to redirect the user to the homepage if the state is empty
    useEffect(() => {
        if (state === null || state === undefined) {
            navigate("/")
            return
        }
        // Clear the state after the user exits from the Success page
        return navigate(pathname, { replace: true })
    })

    if (state === null || state === undefined) {
        return
    }

    console.log("state:", state)
    return (
                  <>
                    <div>
                        Thank you!
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Abbiamo appena inviato un'email a
                        <span>
                            {state.email}
                        </span>
                        con in allegato la tua ricevuta (per favore, controlla la cartella SPAM se non dovessi vederla).
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Puoi anche scaricare la ricevuta facendo click qui:
                        <a download href={getInvoiceUrl()}>
                            Download
                        </a>
                    </div>
                  </>
    )
}

export default Success
```

Comment: what did you get in `state`

Comment: @AbbasHussain `state` is (e.g.) `{email: 'sb-jxe7u14612928@personal.example.com'}` received from `navigate("/success", state)` on the Checkout page.

Comment: @AbbasHussain if I remove the whole `useEffect` part and the `if` statement it works fine but user is always able to access to the success page. I'd like to allow the access just after the successful checkout payment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `state === null || state === undefined` condition you are missing returning valid JSX. Return `null` here to indicate to React there's nothing to render.

```
function Success() {
  // Get the state from navigate on the Checkout page
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Check the state in order to redirect the user to the homepage if the state is empty
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!state) {
      navigate("/", { replace: true }); // <-- redirect to prevent access
      return;
    }
  });

  if (!state) {
    return null; // <-- return valid JSX
  }

  return ( ... );
}
```

OR, to eliminate the need for the `useEffect`, return the `Navigate` component.

```
function Success() {
  // Get the state from navigate on the Checkout page
  const { state } = useLocation();

  if (!state) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />; // <-- return Redirect
  }

  return ( ... );
}
```

Comment: Using the `Navigate` component works well even without removing the `StrictMode`! Furthermore, it's cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

lol I just create the whole scenario of the problem and guess what you don't return anything you need to `return null`

Error: `Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null`

just try this

```
  let { state, pathname } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!state) {
      navigate("/");
    }

    return function cleanup() {
      navigate(pathname, { replace: true });
      navigate("/");
    };
  }, []);

  if (!state) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
      <div>
        Abbiamo appena inviato un'email a<span>{state.email}</span>
        con in allegato la tua ricevuta (per favore, controlla la cartella SPAM
        se non dovessi vederla).
      </div>
  );
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. If I leave the `useEffect` part and the `if` statement outside, the user is ALWAYS redirect to the home, even after the successful checkout. Returning null didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Fixed! the issue check out.

Comment: thanks mate! because of you i also learn new thing.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work. I always get redirected to the home.

Comment: I have tested this myself wait letme create codesandbox

Comment: I created this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-sun-7qtyb6?file=/src/Checkout.jsx

Comment: working fine try to figure out what's the issue Hint: its related to react version 18
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-leakey-o0ette

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22839 that's the issue remove StrictMode tag in index file and see everything will work perfectly fine I was using react 17 version that's why it was working in my machice

Comment: It seems you are right. Let me check!

Comment: Upvote and accept answer if its help.

Comment: Returning the `Navigate` component instead the `navigate()` hook works even without removing the `StrictMode`.